# windows NDIS intermediate (IM) driver installation programmatically

Tags: windows, installation, device-driver, ndis

I am learning windows NDIS Intermediate(IM) driver development.I am getting problem in installation . I always need to install it manually.

My question is how can i do NDIS intermediate (IM) driver  installation programmatically

Regards

Navaneeth

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an example of how to do this in the WinDDK.  Just look through the NDIS example code, specifically (if I remember right), the NDIS Passthru Driver has installer code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the INetCfg API. The DDK contains a sample called BindView which demonstrates how to use this.

Specifically the file netcfgapi.cpp have nice wrappers for what you want to do.

Referring to the wrappers there, you'll need to call:

```
HrGetInetCfg()
HrInstallComponent()
Call Apply() on the interface received earlier.
Start your service (driver) by calling upon the SCM.
HrReleaseInetCfg()
```